# Converting mp4 audio to webm with ffmpeg - unable to find suitable output for webm

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, mp4, webm, vorbis

I have a custom heroku buildpack that is installing ffmpeg, libvorbis, etc.

When I run `ffmpeg` I get the following output:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.

configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jan 24 2013 19:42:59, gcc: 4.4.3
At least one output file must be specified
```

I'm trying to convert mp4 audio to webm audio.

Here is the command I am using:

```
~/public/audio $ ffmpeg -i sample.mp3 sample.webm
```

And the output:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jan 24 2013 19:42:59, gcc: 4.4.3
Input #0, mp3, from 'sample.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:01.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 76 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'sample.webm'
```

This works fine on my OSX install, but on Ubuntu 14.04 I'm getting these errors.

What do I need to do so .webm files can be the destination?

Comment: Thank you. I will post there for these questions from now on.